# Gradle job failed in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle

We see below error while running gradle build in jenkins.

**Error Detatils:**

[Gradle] - Launching build.
[Sample_Proj] $ cmd.exe /C "C:\CI-Softwares\gradle-2.14.1\bin\gradle.bat -b setup.gradle update && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Sample_Proj\setup.gradle' line: 5

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Sample_Proj'.

Could not get unknown property 'coe_artifactory_url' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.774 secs
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE

Could you plese help me, How can i fix in this issue

Comment: Solving that will require us to have a look at your `setup.gradle` file.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the `coe_artifactory_url` property is not declared. I assume you have a `gradle.properties` file. Make sure to declare the property in this file like this:
`coe_artifactory_url=http://www.example.com/repo`

Be aware of case sensitivity, so double check your spelling.

Then in your `build.gradle` file you have something like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
     url project.coe_artifactory_url
    }
}
```